# All sales reports in magento are completely empty

Tags: magento, report

We are using Magento 1.9.1.1 and we already had quiet a lot of orders in our online shop. But when navigating to Reports in the top bar navigation of the admin panel, and then choosing `Sales -> Reports`, ALL reports are completely empty. There are no blank or empty lines, there are absolutely NO lines.

We also have already tried different things to solve this, which could be found by google:

- Different websites (all websites, Main website, german, etc...)
- updating statistics several times...
- `UPDATE sales_flat_order_item SET store_id=2 WHERE store_id IS NULL;`

Nothing has helped!

Any advise here?

Best regards
Alex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay... that was really dump.... I've tried so many things since ONE WEEK! I've searched google and searched, and searched....

Now, suddenly... after I have posted the question above, some few minutes later, I saw the Button "Show report", which was there all the time I guess.

I've clicked that button and all orders are shown below in the list... then I was able to export them...

Sorry for disturbing anybody.... :P

Comment: I've assumed some ajax stuff there to show the results... I never expected the need to click a button for showing the list... :-P ...what a surprise...
That is so... ashaming... I should delete this whole thread... *g*

Comment: It is not ! One of my customers had the exact same issue as you. The problem is not your, it's the very bad UX, bad design.